# Add Identity to a separate class library in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-identity

I have 2 projects in my solution. The first is a web app using Razor pages, the second is a class library with 3 sub directories:

```
Entities
DAL (data access Layer, which contains the `DBContext`)
BLL (business logic layer)
```

I've seen a few problems on this but only for ASP.NET MVC web apps.

Is there a separate way of doing this with razor pages or can I just use the same methods for my setup?

Edit:
I managed to figure it out. I was able to have the dbcontext in my DAL folder inherit from Identity Context and then register that with the builder in my Program file. The next part was a bit tedious as I had to change all instances of Identity user in the identity Area folder to my Application user class